# How to set the binding of RichEditBox text in code behind

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I can set text in RichEditBox through Document Property, but i would like to bind text from RichTextBox with my model. I could easly set binding with TextBox but I have no idea how to do this with RichEditBox, any help would be welcome:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a new control that inherits from the original RichEditBox. It contains an additional Dependency Property RtfText which I can bind.

[RichEditBoxExtended Class Source Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549156/winrt-binding-a-rtf-string-to-a-richeditbox/26549205#26549205)

This works for me!

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe it's possible to perform a two-way binding to the Document property as it's not defined as a Dependency Property.  In a case like this, I believe it would be ok to use code-behind to pass your document data to the RichTextBox, and then use an event handler to pass the document back to your view model as needed.  No logic in the code behind, but simple data passing.