# RichEditBox two-way binbing does not work [Windows Store App]

Tags: c#, data-binding, binding, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have RichEditBox and class with DependencyPropert:

```
public class RichTextC : DependencyObject
{
    public static string GetRichText(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(RichTextProperty);
    }

    public static void SetRichText(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(RichTextProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RichTextProperty =  DependencyProperty.Register("RichText", typeof(string), typeof(RichTextC), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, callback));

    private static void callback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var reb = (RichEditBox)d;
        reb.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, (string)e.NewValue);
    }
 }
```

And this is my RichEditBox in XAML file:

```
<RichEditBox local:RichTextC.RichText="{Binding MyRichText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Problem is, that View can be notified by the View Model, but when I change text in RichEditBox it not notify View Model. I mean, binding working only in one way, from View Model to View, but from View to View Model does not work.

How can I change it to two-way binding start working?

Comment: The following worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549156/winrt-binding-a-rtf-string-to-a-richeditbox

Comment: @dschüsä Thank You for reply.But I have question. How can I use Your code? I don't know how can I add this control to my xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I cannot comment, I have to rewrite my answer! :-(

1. Create a class and name it RichEditBoxExtended
2. Replace the class code with the code from [WinRt: Binding a RTF String to a RichEditBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549156/winrt-binding-a-rtf-string-to-a-richeditbox/26549205#26549205) (please recopy I changed the visibility of the class)
3. Go to your XAML and enter:
   `<local:RichTextBoxExtended RtfText="{Binding MyRichText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>`

I hope this helps...

Comment: I have still some strange problem ;/. In my project I created folder Constrols. in Controls folder I created RichEditBoxExtended class with Your code. Then I xaml I add this: _xmlns:controls="using:StringSearcher.Controls"_ and this _<controls:RichEditBoxExtended RtfText="{Binding MyRichText, Mode=TwoWay}" />_ and then I got error, that  "RichEditBoxExtended" does not exist in my namespace. I don't understand why.

Comment: Try to compile (clean and rebuild) the project before you add the control or perhaps you have to restart visual studio... There are some strange caching beviours in Visual Studio...

Comment: Of course I tried to clean and rebuild application, but it still does not work. I don't thought to try reset VS. After Your suggestion I try to reset and it fix my issue. Thank You. :)

Comment: This code works, but if the bound observablecollection changes then it wont reflect back in the RichEditBoxExtended. Any clue as to how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wire up code to set the RichText property when the RichEditBox's Document's Text changes. To do this handle the RichEditBox.TextChanged event to update the RichText property. You'll need to include some code to prevent the RichText property from updating the RichEditBox's Document's text when handling the TextChanged event (or vice versa) to prevent looping.