# How To Format the Text of a RichEditBox inside ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I am using a simple MVVM pattern to bind string data to a RichEditBox.

The RichEditBox is in the DataTemplate of a ListView...

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Result">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Button Content="Bold" Click="button1_Click"/>              
                        <local:RichEditBoxExtended RtfText="{x:Bind MyString, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

The Result class looks like this...

```
public class Result
        {
            public Result(string sentence)
            {
                MyString = sentence;
            }
            public string MyString { get; set; }
        }
```

As was probably noticed, I am not using RichEditBox but **RichEditBoxExtended**, or a control that inherits from RichEditBox. Here is [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549156/winrt-binding-a-rtf-string-to-a-richeditbox) to this topic and the RichEditBoxExtended class is being included for convenience...

```
public class RichEditBoxExtended : RichEditBox
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RtfTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
            "RtfText", typeof(string), typeof(RichEditBoxExtended),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(string), RtfTextPropertyChanged));

        private bool _lockChangeExecution;

        public RichEditBoxExtended()
        {
            TextChanged += RichEditBoxExtended_TextChanged;
        }

        public string RtfText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(RtfTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RtfTextProperty, value); }
        }

        private void RichEditBoxExtended_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_lockChangeExecution)
            {
                _lockChangeExecution = true;
                string text;
                Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out text);
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
                {
                    RtfText = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, out text);
                    RtfText = text;
                }
                _lockChangeExecution = false;
            }
        }

        private static void RtfTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        {
            var rtb = dependencyObject as RichEditBoxExtended;
            if (rtb == null) return;
            if (!rtb._lockChangeExecution)
            {
                rtb._lockChangeExecution = true;
                rtb.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, rtb.RtfText);
                rtb._lockChangeExecution = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

What I would now like to be able to do is highlight text inside a RichEditBoxExtended instance and then make it bold by clicking the Bold button in the DataTemplate. How can something like this be accomplished?

Comment: Consider rewriting your question to focus on the question itself.

Comment: Hopefully, it's a little clearer now :)